# Split lines from stdout saved in a set

Tags: python, string, split, set

I have an output from stdout which gives me a set looking something like this:

```
output = {'This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3\n'}
```

Now, I am looking what is the best way to extract each line and store them in separate strings. I've tried using something like this below but it doesn't really split the lines.

```
st = str(output)
outputSplit = st.splitlines()
```

or

```
outputSplit = output.split('\n', 1)[0]
```

I would assume I am missing something simple as I am just starting out with python. What would be the best way to achieve what I am looking for?

Cheers

Comment: I believe when you convert output to str it automatically escapes the \n so splitlines will not work because they are replaced with \\n

Comment: @siralexsir88 that is not true.

Comment: @AnnZen Python 3.8 that is exactly what happens. `output = {'This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3\n'}
print(str(output).splitlines())`

Comment: But if you take the string out of the set, it turns back into newline, same for when you add strings with \n to lists.

Comment: @siralexsir88  converting `set` object to `string` is wrong, plus using this will include extra curly brackets

Comment: @sahasrara62 I was simply offering an explanation to why that method was not working, of course it is not the best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
output = {'This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3\n'}
strings = output.pop().strip().split('\n')
print(strings)
```

Output:

```
['This is line 1', 'This is line 2', 'This is line 3']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
output.pop().splitlines()
```

output

```
['This is line 1', 'This is line 2', 'This is line 3']
```